How to add text to a PDF without significantly Increasing filesize?
I am trying to use Apache PDFBox to add text to existing PDF pages while keeping the file size increase minimal. My goal is to expand the page height, shift the current content upwards, and add the new text at the bottom of the page.
Initially, I used an image-based approach, copying the original page's content as an image and placing it on a newly created page. This caused the file size to grow significantly—from 3 MB to 30 MB for a single PDF.
To reduce the size impact, I switched to a content-based approach, directly manipulating the content instead of converting it to an image. While this approach reduced the file size increase, the size still tripled—for example, a 3 MB file grows to 9 MB.
I am looking for an effective solution to add text while keeping the file size increase negligible, or at least much smaller than the current results.
Any insights into efficient methods, optimizations, or alternative approaches to achieve this using Apache PDFBox would be greatly appreciated.
What I Tried:
I initially used an image-based approach, where I copied the content of the original page as an image and placed it on the new page with adjusted layout.
Result: The PDF file size increased drastically (e.g., from 3 MB to 30 MB).
I switched to a content-based approach, where I directly manipulated the content to shift it upwards and added the new text.
Result: While this reduced the size impact, the file size still tripled (e.g., from 3 MB to 9 MB).
To Copy the content:
    // Access the source page's content stream
        COSStream sourceStream = (COSStream) sourcePage.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.CONTENTS);

            COSStream newStream = document.getDocument().createCOSStream();
            try (InputStream inputStream = sourceStream.createInputStream();
                 OutputStream outputStream = newStream.createOutputStream()) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }

            destinationPage.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.CONTENTS, newStream);

            destinationPage.setResources(sourcePage.getResources());
        

To shift the content upwards:
        try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, 
                                                PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, true, true)) {
            contentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(0, shiftAmount)); 
        }

What I Expected:
I expected to add text to the PDF without causing such a significant increase in file size, ideally with minimal or negligible growth in size.
What Actually Happened:
Both approaches led to noticeable file size increases—especially the image-based one. The content-based approach performed better but was still far from the desired result.

I assume you're familiar with PDF's internal structure - so do you know why the file-size is increasing or what parts of the PDF grew?  Can you confirm that PDFBox is not re-encoding any images or adding any empty/zero-valued padding to the end of the file?

Which PDFBox version do you use?

You don't have to shift the content; just alter the page boxes (e.g Crop box and Media box) to expand the page. (What happens if you add text without moving the content? Does the file size expand then?)

What mkl hints at is that is that the described effect can happen with PDFBox 2.0.* with accessible PDFs (which have a lot of objects in the structure tree). It won't happen with 3.0.* because that one can create compressed object streams. I bet that the effect even happens if the OP just opens and saves the PDF.
